# How to add OK Button to Primefaces MessageDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

The `Primefaces` Showcase demonstrates the Use of a `FacesMessage` in a dialog [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/message.xhtml)

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "What we do in life", "Echoes in eternity.");
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
```

Now, i would like to add an OK Button below the Text instead of the "X" in the upper right corner. 
I cant find an easy way to do this, but it should be relatively easy, shouldnt it?

Comment: You can have a custom dialog with <dialog> tag, put it to the template and use it across your application